# Why it's not possible to override the getHeight() and getWidth() methods on custom views?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have found some similar questions, but I think they don't quite completely clear my doubts.

I'm  developing a custom view, directly extending the `View` class. The thing is, I'm creating a parallax view, which means it swipes all the way until the end of the background image. Being said that, I wanted to override the `View.getWidth()` method so it returns the width of the bitmap.

My `View.onMeasure()` overriden method sets the measured width as the intended background bitmap width which is expected to be wider than the actual display. What happens is that instead the call to the `getWidth()` method returns the device display width. And that's why I wanted to override the `View.getWidth()` method, which is not possible because it's a final method.

So, all I want to know is why they made it so it shouldn't be allowed to override this method, and what would be the impact on the view hierarchy if it was?

Comment: why does View.onMeasure() measures width as bitmap width?  what is the purpose  for that?

Comment: At first, my first thought was so that the Scroller needed that. But I wanted to make it so there would be no inconsistencies with other views, since the view would have at least the bitmap width. But I'm not sure if my line of thinking is correct. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: onMeasure returns physical dimensions of your View, not a virtual size

Comment: @pskink I guess that clears my doubts since the maximum width `View.getWidth()` yields is the actual device's display physical width in pixels, there's no point in overriding the method.